# What is a more reliable way to wait for a service to be up and running in Drone before one of the steps tries to connect to it?

Tags: pipeline, drone.io

See this section from [Drone's official documentation](https://docs.drone.io/pipeline/docker/syntax/services/):

```
kind: pipeline
type: docker
name: default

steps:
  - name: ping
    image: redis
    commands:
    - sleep 5
    - redis-cli -h cache ping

services:
  - name: cache
    image: redis
```

Afterwards, it gives this advice:

> Be sure to give the service adequate time to initialize before
> attempting to connect. A naive solution is to use the sleep command.

I need a more reliable way to wait for the service to initialise before connecting to it in one of the steps in my drone.yml file. The issue with just using the sleep command is I don't know how long it may take for a particular service to initialise.